# PyMC: how can I use a custom sampler for one specific variable in a model?

Tags: bayesian, python, markov-chain-montecarlo, pymc

Basically I have a function to efficiently sample one variable in my model that I would like PyMC to use, along with its normal samplers for everything else. Since I have this function I don't have a need to define a log likelihood for the variable either.

Can I do this using the `Stochastic` class and making a `random` function? Or do I need to make a custom step method?

Answer (score 3):

I think you will need to make a custom step method.  This is what I did for a project on sampling random spanning trees with PyMC2, and you can see my [spanning tree Metropolis step method here](https://github.com/aflaxman/pymc-networkx-bdst/blob/master/models.py#L128).

Here is a minimal PyMC2 version:

```
class StandardNormal(pm.Gibbs):
    def __init__(self, stochastic, verbose=None):
        pm.Gibbs.__init__(self, stochastic, verbose=verbose)

    def step(self):
        self.stochastic.value = np.random.normal()

A = pm.Uninformative('A', value=0)
B = pm.Normal('B', mu=20+A, tau=10)

mc = pm.MCMC([A,B])
mc.use_step_method(StandardNormal, A)
mc.sample(iter=5000, burn=100)
```

And here is a corresponding PyMC3 version:

```
class StandardNormal(object):
    def __init__(self, var):
        self.var = var.name

    def step(self, point):
        new = point.copy()
        new[self.var] = np.random.normal()

        return new

with pm.Model() as model:
    A = pm.Flat('A')
    B = pm.Normal('B', mu=20+A, sd=10)

    step_A = StandardNormal(var=A)
    step_B = pm.step_methods.Metropolis(vars=[B])


    trace = pm.sample(5000, [step_A, step_B])
```

You can see it [all in action here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/aflaxman/91d462301855d6942506).

Comment: Thanks, I also just came across [this](https://github.com/aflaxman/gbd/blob/birth-prev/fit_posterior.py#L92-99) (written by you I believe!) which seems relevant and fairly straightforward. Any idea if it is compatible with PyMC3? I'm still a bit surprised this isn't as simple as providing a `Stochastic` with just a `random` function and having PyMC recognize that automatically.

Comment: Followup question: if I used a custom step method for sampling one of my variables, then how do I even define the variable in PyMC given that I don't want to bother with a log likelihood function (since I'm defining my own sampler)?

Comment: It looks like you got the answer already [on github](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc/issues/542), but I will update here in case future searchers find this page.